# Problems finding an LSTM model for classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, keras, lstm

I am doing a study for the classification of musical genres using deep learning techniques. The work consists of making a classification using an LSTM model.

I am using GTZAN as a data set, and preprocessing them using Librosa. This way I obtain the spectral characteristics, specifically: Spectral centroid.

My input data has the following size: X_train (750, 20, 1249).

My model is:

```
model = Sequential ()
model.add (LSTM (units = 512, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape [1], X_train.shape [2])))
model.add (LSTM (units = 32, return_sequences = False))

model.add (Dense (units = 10, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile (loss = losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                 optimizer = Adam (),
                 metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

model.summary ()

I get these results:
[image: Model Accuracy]

[image]

I scale also my data using MinMaxScaler.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are preprocessing the data using Librosa ( maybe extracting MFCCs ), I assume that the preprocessing is correct and needs no intervention.

On viewing the first two layers,

```
model.add (LSTM (units = 512, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape [1], X_train.shape [2])))
model.add (LSTM (units = 32, return_sequences = False))
```

You can notice that the difference between the units present in the layers is quite huge ( 512 and 32 ). Hence the 512-dimensional data is packed in a 32-dimensional vector immediately in the next layer.

> You can try reducing this difference. You can use 64 - 32 units in both the layers.

Also, most sources and blogs, say that for recurrent neural networks, RMS optimizer is the best choice. Since we use the hyperbolic tangent activation function, there is a problem with it called exploding gradients. RMSProp optimizer can handle such problems efficiently since the square root of gradients is utilised here.

> Try using the `RMSProp` optimizer with a low learning rate.

I haven't tried this myself, but you can use `recurrent` or `input` dropout in LSTMs. They may help you to overcome the overfitting problem.

> Also, you can try adding some more `Dense` layers with `Dropout` layers in between them.

**Tip:**

LSTMs commonly face the problem of overfitting, so you can implement any of the other methods which are meant to eliminate overfitting. Also, as a common step you can try reducing the batch sizd during training.

Comment: Another way that you can regularize a LSTM is to have it also learn to predict the next step at the same time. This is a much more difficult assignment with the 2 loss functions. With only 750 samples and 1249 time steps, this will definitely be prone to overfitting. This might help, as well as other regularization techniques.